# How to use the nth selector for all items after n?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Let's say for example I have the following list:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a>Explore</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        <li><a>Blog</a></li>
        <li><a>blah</a></li>
        <li><a>boo</a></li>
        <li><a>ahh</a></li>
    </ul>
```

How do I control all items after List item number four?

Comment: `ul > li:nth-child(n+5) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king) gave the answer, for example:

```
ul > li:nth-child(n+5) {
    color: blue;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7yVKS/

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo